# Индексы по двум полям mongo

Tags: mongodb, index, aggregation-framework

Например, ip = 123.123.123.132. Нужно сделать агрегацию с такой выборкой

```
                  {
                  $match: {$or:[
                    {srcaddr:ip},
                    {dstaddr:ip}
                  ]}
                  }
```

Какой индекс оптимальней строить? Композитный, такой:

```
([ ("dstaddr",1),("srcaddr",1)], unique=False)
```

или проиндексировать отдельно?

И ещё тот же вопрос по столбцам с выборкой:

```
                  first:{
                    $lte: stop
                  },
                  last: {
                    $gte: start
                  },
```

Answer (score 1):

В случае с $match и $or внутри лучше иметь 2 отдельных индекса

```
1) { "srcaddr":1 }
2) { "dstaddr":1 }
```

Монга использует оба их них для запроса и потом соединит результаты вместе.
На второй запрос лучше использовать compound index

```
{ first:1, last:1 }
```